# The same interface inherited several times

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, interface

For example I have the code bellow:

```
public interface IFoo1
{
    void Foo1();
}

public interface IFoo2
{
    void Foo2();
}

public interface IOne : IFoo1
{
    void One();
}

public interface IFooList : IFoo1, IFoo2
{

}

public interface ITwo : IOne, IFooList
{

}

public class Test : ITwo
{
    public void Foo1()
    {
    }

    public void One()
    {
    }

    public void Foo2()
    {
    }
}
```

Interesting that class `ITwo` inherits `IFoo1` twice(from `IOne` and from `IFooList`) Is it a bad practice ?
I use these titles just for simplifying. But I have the same inheritance hierarchy in my prod code. And is it serious problem to have such type of inheritance ?

Comment: Why wouldn't `ITwo` just inherit from `IOne` and `IFoo2`?  `IFooList` has nothing in it

Comment: This is more of a code review question than a SO question, but it's sometimes necessary.  It is, however, a little code-smelly. Typically, when you find yourself with inheritance loops, it's time to reconsider your code structure and see *why* it's looping.

Comment: It depends. Do you really want to use `IFooList` classes as if they were IFoo1 or IFoo2 or was this a quick & dirty way to add Foo1 and Foo2 to some classes? And why doens't `ITwo` inherit from theIFoos. If there *is* an `is-a` relation it's not *necessarily* bad. Otherwise it's very bad - quick&dirty fixes are typically very dirty

Comment: @maccettura I have more complicated inheritance hierarchy. it's just example to explain the problem.

Comment: Interfaces are *interfaces*, in the way headphone sockets, wall sockets, USB sockets are interfaces. If you want multiple adapters on a device, you add multiple adapters to the device. You don't try to create one adapter that will fill accept any cable, any voltage, any signal

Comment: @CDove thanks. I got your point

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I very appreciate your comment. It helps me. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

There is a flaw in your inheritance chain. This can be more easily observed if we apply some names that make sense.

Your code in its current form:

```
public interface IAnimal
{
    void Breathe();
}

public interface ILegged
{
    void Stand();
}

public interface IFlyingAnimal : IAnimal
{
    void Fly();
}

public interface ILeggedAnimal : IAnimal, ILegged
{

}

public interface IBird : IFlyingAnimal, ILeggedAnimal
{

}

public class Eagle : IBird
{
    public void Breathe()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Stand()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Fly()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

As you can see, `IBird` is both an `IFlyingAnimal` and an `ILeggedAnimal`, which is fine from a compiler perspective, but there is overlap because they are both an `IAnimal`.

What you need, apparently, is an `IFlyingAnimal` that is `ILegged`:

```
public interface IBird : IFlyingAnimal, ILegged
{

}
```

That will give you a proper chain of inheritance.

You now have and `Eagle` that is an `IBird`, which is an `IFlyingAnimal` that is `ILegged`. It can `Breathe`, `Stand` in its legs and `Fly`.

Comment: upvote for great example
but production code is completely different ))

Comment: @isxaker: It's your exact same code with different names... :-)

Comment: Yes, I know. But I've already mentioned it is simplified version. Anyway thanks